# Catching command-line errors using %x

Tags: ruby, command-line

Whenever you want to execute something on the command line, you can use the following syntax:

```
%x(command to run)
```

However, I want to catch an error or at least get the response so I can parse it correctly. I tried setting:

```
result = %x(command to run)
```

and using a try-catch

```
begin
  %x(command to run)
rescue
  "didn't work"
end
```

to no avail. How can I capture the results instead of having them printed out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So this doesn't directly answer your question (won't capture the command's output).  But instead of trying `begin`/`rescue`, you can just check the exit code (`$?`) of the command:

```
%x(command to run)
unless $? == 0
   "ack! error occurred"
end
```

**Edit**: Just remembered this new project.  I think it does exactly what you want:

https://github.com/envato/safe_shell

Answer (score 13):

You might want to redirect **stderr** to **stdout**:

```
result = %x(command to run 2>&1)
```

Or if you want to separate the error messages from the actual output, you can use popen3:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("find /proc")
```

Then you can read the actual output from stdout and error messages from stderr.

Comment: its still prints everything out... and there's nothing in those variables... they are all nil

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to use Ruby's open3:

```
require 'open3'
include Open3

stdin, stdout, stderr = popen3('date')
stdin.close

puts
puts "Reading STDOUT"
print stdout.read
stdout.close

puts
puts "Reading STDERR"
print stderr.read
stderr.close
# >> 
# >> Reading STDOUT
# >> Sat Jan 22 20:03:13 MST 2011
# >> 
# >> Reading STDERR
```

[`popen3`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open3/1.9.2/frames) returns IO streams for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, allowing you to do I/O to the opened app.

Many command-line apps require their STDIN to be closed before they'll process their input.

You have to read from the returned STDOUT and STDERR pipes. They don't automatically shove content into a mystical variable.

In general, I like using a block with `popen3` because it handles cleaning up behind itself.

Look through the examples in the [Open3](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open3/1.9.2/frames) doc. There's lots of nice functionality.

Answer (score 9):

You need a mix of @Cam 's answer and @tonttu 's answer.

`decent explanation of $? and others.`

Edit: the domain `http://blog.purifyapp.com` is now in hands of a domain-squatter and scammer.

```
result = %x(command to run 2>&1)

unless $? == 0 #check if the child process exited cleanly.
    puts "got error #{result}"
end
```