# Catch error produced by .sh with ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, sh

There is a shell script that I run from ruby, this shell script sends errors to the OS, I cannot catch it through unless or  `echo $?` because they are not exceptions and the script runs correctly.

How could I catch or search if the error was produced?

E.g.: The error [1002] is produced, how would a catch it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching command-line errors using %x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771930/catching-command-line-errors-using-x)

Comment: You are righ jetAbe, I dont know why it works doing the $? directly and not the echo $?, but it worked thanks

Comment: Duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771930/catching-command-line-errors-using-x